# how to output string of specific length using agrep in R

Tags: r

I have a load of DNA sequences.

I want to match a part of the sequence and I want to return the match up to a specific length

The dataframe df has the columns:

V1 and V2

```
>chr1:61695-62229      aattccaagagtattattgcaccaaaaggcatggacttaaaattcttgatacatgatttcaaaatattttctttaaggtttgaatcagtctatattccctccagcagcgtataaaagtgccaatttctctgatccttagccagtttgggtaataataattgtaaaacttttttttctttttttttgagacagagtctccctctgtcgccaggctgaagtgcagtggcgcaatctcggctcactgcaacctccgcctcccggggtcaagctattctcctgcctcagcctcccaagtagctgggactacaggcatgcaccaccatgcccagctaatttttgttatttttagtagagatggagtttccccatgttggacaggatggtctcgatctcttgacctcgtgatccaccctcctcggcctcccaaagtgctgggataacaggcgtgaacaaccatgcccggcctgtaaaactttttcctaatttaacagaaaaataatagtattatattttatcatatttctttgatttcta

>chr1:101718-102194   taaaaataaatgtattaagtatgaacaacaaaaaagctagtaaaggttgaacaacaactatccttaggaaagtggaaataatgtattaataaatatgaaagcaggctagccacggtgactcacatctgtaatcccagcactttgggaggctgaggcaggcagatcacctgaggtcaggagttccagaccagcctggccaacatggtgaaatcttgtctctcctacaaatacaaaaactagccaggcttggttgtgcactcctgtaattcgagctacttgggaggctgaggcaggagaatctcttgaacctgagaggcagaggttgcagtgagccaagatcatgccactgcactccagctggggcaacagagtgacactccatctcaaaataaataaataagaaagcagaaactaataaactagaaaacagaaacatagaactaatttataaatcaaagcactatgccttgaaaaga
```

I have used agrep to get the match.

```
RepeatAlusSequencesdfMatch <- RepeatAlusSequencesdf[agrep("aacctcaaagactggcctca", RepeatAlusSequencesdf[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, max.distance = 0.3), ]
```

but I also want to return a length of 146 characters from the end of the match. At the moment it is giving me the entire sequence which I can't use

Comment: You can't capture groups in agrep like you do with grep. You can't say "give me the matching substring". You say: "here is a sequence of strings, find which ones match this template by using the smallest number of insertions, deletions or substitutions" and the algorithm just returns you the matching strings. Their matching or non-matching is calculated on the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above. I don't think you can achieve what you are trying to do here with agrep. If the DNA sequence you are trying to fuzzy-match has predictable number and positions of nucleotide insertion/deletion/substitutions then just use one (or several) regular expressions with capture groups to extract what you need.

If the differences are not predictable and you truly need a fuzzy match, you could use a brute-force algorithm like the following:

1. Break up each of your DNA strings into random positions such as to produce different 146 nucleotide long sequences.
2. Using a "threshold" max.distance run agrep on the resulting sequences and select those that match.
3. From the above set select out the best matches by running agrep using successively smaller max.distances until you get the one(s) you are interested in.

The more different 146 nucleotide sequences you select the more accurate result you will get. If you want to find *the* best match, use an exhaustive search by walking each DNA sequence from the beginning, breaking it to 146 nucleotide pieces and running the above algorithm then leaving one nucleotide out from the beginning, selecting the next partitions and so on until the end.

Hope this helps or gives better ideas.

Comment: If I get agrep to return the match then I can insert this into a new column and then to a proper grep to return the match and 146 extra nucleotides. But how cna I get agrep to return the match?

Comment: Or is there an alternative package that will return the match itself?

Comment: You can only get the entire matching sequence. The "match itself" is the *entire matching sequence*. To better understand this, google "Levenshtein distance".